# Can secret room affect spaces acquired by merits?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, mage-the-awakening-2e, merits

Secret room is on page 178 of the new edition of Mage the Awakening,  and stated it can increase the space of a room:

> the subject space’s volume is increased or decreased a number of steps along the Area Scale factor table equal to the spell’s Potency.

Now I don't see why this would be not be allowed, but I'm sure other spells  that increase/provide merit dots explicitly mention it.

It seems like this could replace some versions of merits (like sanctum)  that track location size,  if this spell were made lasting.

Likewise demenses that can either be acquired by merits or in game effort are related to size. Are they effected?

Does casting and extending this spell to lasting provide or interact with the various versions of safe space merits in any way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Merits such as Sanctum and Safe Place do not deal only with the size of the place. Safe Place (p. 107) for example grants you an initiative bonus and gives external attackers penalties. Sanctum increases your spell control limit (p. 104). None of this things are achievable simply by making the place bigger.

Regarding the Demesne, you could make the space which **contains** the Demesne larger, but then the Demesne itself will stop covering the full area. That is, the Demesne is not merely the space that contains it. The only way to make a Demesne larger is by pooling up to 5 Soul stones or putting multiple Demesnes side by side (p. 99)

Answer (score 1):

[Disclaimer] I do not have the new version of Mage.

I would rule in this case that the caster must have a space to start with- at least O in the appropriate Safe Space (Size) merit.

After this, it depends on how you like to play. If narratively adding dots is acceptable in your games, then a Lasting spell would indeed provide free dots of an appropriate Size merit. However, what is given can be taken away. Should the magic ever be dispelled, those free dots vanish as if they never were.

If you prefer to have some sort of cost or restriction for magically-provided merits, things get slightly more difficult. For instance, in Mage: the Ascension, when a Life Mage used magic to increase his Physical attributes and then wanted to make the increase permanent, he still paid XP, but only half the normal cost. A similar rule for the new system could allow for OO of Size to be purchased for only 1XP, for instance, but only O of those OO would be protected by Sanctity of Merits (and both would be lost if the aforementioned dispel occurred).